# Copying SD Cards with "LaCie d2 Network"

Tags: usb, sd-card, usb-flash-drive, card-reader, lacie

The [LaCie d2 Network](http://www.lacie.com/uk/products/product.htm?pid=11247) has a feature where by you can attach a USB drive and press the blue button at the from and it will copy the drive contents (no computer required). (See this [review](http://www.reghardware.co.uk/2009/07/11/review_storage_network_lacie_d2_network/) for more info).

> USB 2.0 and eSATA ports are also
>   provided but these are not designed
>   for extending the d2 Network's
>   storage. Rather, they allow you to
>   connect portable drives for uploading
>   their data to the d2 Network directly.
>   The process is quite slick, too: just
>   plug in a drive and press the big blue
>   button on the front of the unit to
>   trigger an immediate upload. This
>   copies over everything on the external
>   device and seems ideal for camera use.

[image: LaCie d2 Network]

Is it possible to use an microSD or SD card adapter (like the [Kingston MobileLite 9-in-1](http://www.kingston.com/flash/mobilelite_reader.asp)) and copy the contents of the card?

I'm assuming the card reader just "looks like" a normal USB flash drive the computer or (in this case) *LaCie d2 Network*.

Is this assumption correct? Do you know any reason why this won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to vary somewhat. I have a multi-card reader and it actually shows up as 4 separate drives on Windows, one of which has the card you plugged in. I have no idea what the LaCie would do with that. You'd probably have your best luck with a single-format reader, as that is least likely to have oddities that would confuse the drive.

Basically: You're gonna have to buy one and test it, if you want to find out.